# There are no printable documents related to selected orders. Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

First of all am new to magento development. just started from the scratch. I have Setup My magento e-Commerce Portal. The Problem which am Struggling with is Printing Invoice.

When Ever I select any order and print its invoice its says **"There are no printable documents related to selected orders."**. dont whats wrong

AM using Magento 2 and PHP 5.6

Tried Google solution's but none of them Works.

Vikas Kumar

Comment: look into this.Hope it may help. https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/There-are-no-printable-documents-related-to-selected-orders/td-p/12351

Comment: @Ranjith I have tried these Solution but strange thing with solution is i have only one method in my file. i dont have **abstract public function __construct()** in FileParserDataSource.php file . technically speaking this solution didnt work

Comment: I have checked with Magento ver. 2.0.6 but not found any issue

Answer (score 0):

Provided details (identified the issue in a wrong query used in filtering invoices to be printed) in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4974

This only happens when order ids diverge from invoice ids, which is inevitable unless you invoice all orders, and do that in the same order as orders have been placed.